# With Delphi 6/7, how can I convert an AnsiString in a different CharSet, to hex String UTF-8?

Tags: delphi, unicode, hex, codepages, ansistring

I need to draw a barcode (QR) with Delphi 6/7. The program can run in various windows locales, and the data is from an input box.

On this input box, the user can choose a charset, and input his own language. This works fine. The input data is only ever from the same codepage. Example configurations could be:

- Windows is on Western Europe, Codepage 1252 for ANSI text
- Input is done in Shift-JIS ANSI charset

I need to get the Shift-JIS across to the barcode. The most robust way is to use hex encoding.

So my question is: how do I go from Shift-JIS to a hex String in UTF-8 encoding, if the codepage is not the same as the Windows locale?

As example: I have the string `能ラ`. This needs to be converted to `E883BDE383A9` as per UTF-8. I have tried this but the result is different and meaningless:

```
String2Hex(UTF8Encode(ftext))
```

Unfortunately I can't just have an inputbox for WideStrings. But if I can find a way to convert the ANSI text to a WideString, the barcode module can work with Unicode Strings as well.

If it's relevant: I am using the TEC-IT TBarcode DLL.

Comment: To convert to `WideString`, look into `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: "*Unfortunately I can't just have an inputbox for Widestrings*" - why not?  That is exactly what you SHOULD do. For instance, you can't enter `能ラ` into a UI that is based on CP1252. There are third-party Unicode UI frameworks available for Delphi 6/7. When dealing with non-ASCII languages, you really need to use Unicode strings, not ANSI strings.

Comment: `UTF8Encode` doesn't work because it too expects a `WideString` and Delphi converts to one using the Windows standard code page (which is wrong here), but it's also (somewhat) broken until Delphi 2009. One you have one, just call `BCSetTextW`.

Comment: Hex seems like an odd choice. Why not base64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Creating and accessing a Unicode text control

This is easier than you may think and I did so in the past with the brand new *Windows 2000* when convenient components like [Tnt Delphi Unicode Controls](https://github.com/rofl0r/TntUnicode) were not available. Having background knowledge on how to create a *Windows* GUI program without using *Delphi*'s VCL and manually creating everything helps - otherwise this is also an introduction of it.

1. First add a property to your form, so we can later access the new control easily:

   ```delphi
   type
     TForm1= class(TForm)
   ...
     private
       hEdit: THandle;  // Our new Unicode control
     end;
   ```
2. Now just create it at your favorite event - I chose `FormCreate`:

   ```delphi
     // Creating a child control, type "edit"
     self.hEdit:= CreateWindowW( PWideChar(WideString('edit')), PWideChar(WideString('myinput')), WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 200, 25, Handle, 0, HINSTANCE, nil );
     if self.hEdit= 0 then begin  // Failed. Get error code so we know why it failed.
       //GetLastError();
       exit;
     end;

     // Add a sunken 3D edge (well, historically speaking)
     if SetWindowLong( self.hEdit, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE )= 0 then begin
       //GetLastError();
       exit;
     end;

     // Applying new extended style: the control's frame has changed
     if not SetWindowPos( self.hEdit, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOSIZE ) then begin
       //GetLastError();
       exit;
     end;

     // The system's default font is no help, let's use this form's font (hopefully Tahoma)
     SendMessage( self.hEdit, WM_SETFONT, self.Font.Handle, 1 );
   ```
3. At some point you want to get the edit's content. Again: how is this done without *Delphi*'s VCL but instead directly with the *WinAPI*? This time I used a button's `Click` event:

   ```delphi
   var
     sText: WideString;
     iLen, iError: Integer;
   begin
     // How many CHARACTERS to copy?
     iLen:= GetWindowTextLengthW( self.hEdit );
     if iLen= 0 then iError:= GetLastError() else iError:= 0;  // Could be empty, could be an error
     if iError<> 0 then begin
       exit;
     end;

     Inc( iLen );  // For a potential trailing #0
     SetLength( sText, iLen );  // Reserve space
     if GetWindowTextW( self.hEdit, @sText[1], iLen )= 0 then begin  // Copy text
       //GetLastError();
       exit;
     end;

     // Demonstrate that non-ANSI text was copied out of a non-ANSI control
     MessageBoxW( Handle, PWideChar(sText), nil, 0 );
   end;
   ```

There are detail issues, like not being able to reach this new control via <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but we're already basically re-inventing *Delphi*'s VCL, so those are details to take care about at other times.

## Converting codepages

The *WinAPI* deals either in [codepages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) (Strings) or in [UTF-16 LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) (WideStrings). For historical reasons (UCS-2 and later) UTF-16 LE fits everything, so this is always the implied target to achieve when coming from codepages:

```delphi
// Converting an ANSI charset (String) to UTF-16 LE (Widestring)
function StringToWideString( s: AnsiString; iSrcCodePage: DWord ): WideString;
var
  iLenDest, iLenSrc: Integer;
begin
  iLenSrc:= Length( s );
  iLenDest:= MultiByteToWideChar( iSrcCodePage, 0, PChar(s), iLenSrc, nil, 0 );  // How much CHARACTERS are needed?
  SetLength( result, iLenDest );
  if iLenDest> 0 then begin  // Otherwise we get the error ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
    if MultiByteToWideChar( iSrcCodePage, 0, PChar(s), iLenSrc, PWideChar(result), iLenDest )= 0 then begin
      //GetLastError();
      result:= '';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The source codepage is up to you: maybe

- `1252` for "Windows-1252" = ANSI Latin 1 Multilingual (Western Europe)
- `932` for "Shift-JIS X-0208" = IBM-PC Japan MIX (DOS/V) (DBCS) (897 + 301)
- `28595` for "ISO 8859-5" = Cyrillic
- `65001` for "UTF-8"

However, if you want to convert from one codepage to another, and both source and target shall not be UTF-16 LE, then you must go forth and back:

1. Convert from ANSI to WIDE
2. Convert from WIDE to a different ANSI

```delphi
// Converting UTF-16 LE (Widestring) to an ANSI charset (String, hopefully you want 65001=UTF-8)
function WideStringToString( s: WideString; iDestCodePage: DWord= CP_UTF8 ): AnsiString;
var
  iLenDest, iLenSrc: Integer;
begin
  iLenSrc:= Length( s );
  iLenDest:= WideCharToMultiByte( iDestCodePage, 0, PWideChar(s), iLenSrc, nil, 0, nil, nil );
  SetLength( result, iLenDest );
  if iLenDest> 0 then begin  // Otherwise we get the error ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
    if WideCharToMultiByte( iDestCodePage, 0, PWideChar(s), iLenSrc, PChar(result), iLenDest, nil, nil )= 0 then begin
      //GetLastError();
      result:= '';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

As per every *Windows* installation not every codepage is supported, or different codepages are supported, so conversion attempts may fail. It would be more robust to aim for a *Unicode* program right away, as that is what every *Windows* installation definitly supports (unless you still deal with *Windows 95*, *Windows 98* or *Windows ME*).

## Combining everything

Now you got everything you need to put it together:

- you can have a *Unicode* text control to directly get it in UTF-16 LE
- you can use an ANSI text control to then convert the input to UTF-16 LE
- you can convert from UTF-16 LE (WIDE) to UTF-8 (ANSI)

## Size

UTF-8 is mostly the best choice, but size wise UTF-16 may need fewer bytes in total when your target audience is Asian: in UTF-8 both `能` and `ラ` need 3 bytes each, but in UTF-16 both only need 2 bytes each. As per your QR barcode size is an important factor, I guess.

Likewise don't waste by turning binary data (8 bits per byte) into ASCII text (displaying 4 bits per character, but itself needing 1 byte = 8 bits again). Have a look at [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which encodes 6 bits into every byte. A concept that you encountered countless times in your life already, because it's used for email attachments.

Comment: Just use TNT Unicode

Comment: The function needed is part of a much larger program, so I can't just use TNT. Anway, I stared myself blind for the longest time. The solution is explained clearly: **In Delphi, font.charset is NOT equal to Codepage under Windows API**. Thus, `SHIFTJIS_CHARSET = $80`, and should use codepage `932`. This was the solution.